# Going through file using iterators

Tags: c++

I have a binary file which containts 10 integers let's say in binary. Is there any way to go through that file using iterators? So far, I just tool those numbers from file and put them into array. But can I avoid using arrays or vectors? Something tells me I might need to overload ++ and —. Hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Read it into a a buffer. Treat the buffer as an array. Are you sure they're in the right endian format? Why avoid arrays when they're the right tool for the job?

Comment: @tadman that's the task :(

Comment: If this is a coding challenge, **get coding**. Remember in C and C++ arrays and pointers are two sides of the same coin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any `std::istream` to read the file, you can use [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and define a custom `operator>>` that uses [`std::istream.read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to read the integers.  For example:

```
struct binary_int
{
    int32_t value; // or whatever type you need
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, binary_int &out)
{
    return in.read((char*)&out.value, sizeof(out.value));
}

{
    std::ifstream inFile(...);

    std::istream_iterator<binary_int> iter(inFile);
    std::istream_iterator<binary_int> end;

    while (iter != end)
    {
        // use iter->value as needed...
        ++iter;
    }
}
```